# Updating a shopping cart without letting updates get lost

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I do not want to put the method def in a synchronized block and still wondering if this can be solved with ConcurrentHashMap?

```
/**
  Implement thread-safe updating of user's cart.
  Exit criteria is carts is updated atomically, product is appended 
  in the end of cart.
**/

void addToCart(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> carts, Integer userId, Integer productId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking the following solution might work but I would welcome any suggestions. I do not think I need to use thread safe list.

```
static void addToCart2(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> carts, Integer userId, Integer productId) {
   carts.putIfAbsent(userId, new ArrayList<>());
   carts.computeIfPresent(userId, (userKey, listValue) -> {
    listValue.add(productId);
    return listValue;
});
```

}